# C# WndProcについて

Tags: c#, winapi

WndProcについての質問です。
プロセスA　→　
　　　　　　　 プロセスC
プロセスB　→

(A,B,Cは別々のアプリです)

プロセスCにWndProcのプロシージャを起動させておきます。
プロセスA,BはプロセスCにプロセス間通信にてwinメッセージを送ります。
プロセスCは受け取ったWinメッセージによって、処理を変えます。

1.プロセスAのメッセージを受信後、すぐにプロセスBからメッセージが来たとします。
プロセスAのメッセージに対しての処理はまだ終わっていません。
この場合、プロセスBのメッセージはどうなるのでしょうか？

2.一度、プロセスCでメッセージを受信をしたら、MessageBox.Showを出すプログラムを作成し試しました。プロセスAのメッセージを受信後、メッセージボックスが表示され、OKボタンを押さずにそのままにしておきます。プロセスBのメッセージ受信後、2つ目のメッセージボックスが表示されました。これは、各メッセージに対して、スレッドが立っているということなのでしょうか。

提示できるコードがなく大変恐縮なのですが、
ご回答いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1.プロセスAのメッセージを受信後、すぐにプロセスBからメッセージが来たとします。 プロセスAのメッセージに対しての処理はまだ終わっていません。 この場合、プロセスBのメッセージはどうなるのでしょうか？

メッセージキューに入っています。

> 2.一度、プロセスCでメッセージを受信をしたら、MessageBox.Showを出すプログラムを作成し試しました。プロセスAのメッセージを受信後、メッセージボックスが表示され、OKボタンを押さずにそのままにしておきます。プロセスBのメッセージ受信後、2つ目のメッセージボックスが表示されました。これは、各メッセージに対して、スレッドが立っているということなのでしょうか。

違います。
プロセスCは1つ目のメッセージボックスを表示したあとすぐにモーダルループといわれるメッセージループに入ります。そこでプロセスBからのメッセージを受けるとウィンドウプロシージャにディスパッチされ、2つ目のメッセージボックスが表示されることになります。
これらは１つのスレッドの中で行われます。